# Why does this python method return a memory address?

Tags: python, methods

I am working on a Python script that digs through a directory full of text files (Dungeon Crawl morgue files, if you're wondering) and extracts and various values. When trying to do this the OOP way I have had some problems.

Here is the GameSummary class which takes in `game_record_list` - this is a List of each individual game records from which I can get the integer value `record.gold`.

```
class GameSummary:

    def __init__(self, game_record_list):
        self.game_record_list = game_record_list
        self.gold_summary = self.gold_report()

    def gold_total(self):
        total_gold = 0
        for record in self.game_record_list:
            total_gold += record.gold
        return total_gold

    def gold_report(self):
        report = "Total gold acquired: " + str(self.gold_total)
        return report
```

Later I instantiate GameSummary as master_summary and try to write the string returned from gold_report into a log file using:

```
log_file.write(master_summary.gold_summary)
```

What ends up being written to my text file, however, is:

"Total gold acquired: bound method GameSummary.gold_total of <**main**.GameSummary instance at 0x02262FD0>"

Why isn't this method returning a string? Is the issue in `gold_total` or `gold_report`?

Comment: By the way, that's not a [memory address](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#id), it's a [repr](http://docs.python.org/library/repr.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
report = "Total gold acquired: " + str(self.gold_total)
```

should be

```
report = "Total gold acquired: " + str(self.gold_total())
```

Alternatively, `gold_total` could be made a property so it could be accessed like a field:

```
@property
def gold_total(self):
    ...
```

Then the first way would work fine.

Answer (score 2):

`str(function)` returns a string containing the address of the function. `str(function())` returns a string representing the value returned by the function.

Comment: I think it bears repeating my comment on the question: A repr is not an address, and need not print one.

Comment: @kojiro, unless you substitute the `repr` method of the function object it will return exactly what I said it does, a string containing the address of the function object. Not that that's terribly useful or anything.